# MemoryMappedFiles in C# for IPC between Docker containers

Tags: ipc, memory-mapped-files, docker-container

Has anybody used MemoryMappedFIles in C# for IPC between 2 Docker containers?

My scenario:
Container 1 : I am writing to a shared memory using [MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.createfromfile?view=netframework-4.8) 
Container 2 : Using [MemoryMappedFIle.OpenExisting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.openexisting?view=netframework-4.8), opening the map created and fetching the data.

Container 1 and 2 are run through "ipc shareable" and "ipc container:container1ID" options respectively to establish IPC.

The data where the shared memory file is referred is through shared volume and is attached to both the containers.

Issue : In general, I am not able to establish communication between two processes in separate windows docker containers.

Note: I am using Windows based containers on docker with .NET Core 3.1 applications.

Please suggest if there are any alternatives to MemoryMappedFiles. (Pipes aren't suitable for my scenario)

Comment: What did you end up doing 

Comment: @JTIM : This was an evaluation topic. Hence the finding that the above wasn't possible itself was significant.

Comment: Same issue here, trying to use InfluxDb https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/get-started/#set-up-influxdb  in docker for windows on Windows Server 2019. Error is `Error: unable to open boltdb: mmap of "/var/lib/influxdb2/influxd.bolt" may not support the MAP_SHARED option` so docker does not seem to support shared memory?

Comment: @Jan: I think so, I even tried using shared volume as shared memory. But still didn't work.